# VS Project / Solution Structure for SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, portable-class-library

I am developing a project using VS2013 that will target WP8, WinRT & Windows Desktop platforms on x86 or x64 architectures.

This project requires local data access / storage and I have selected SQLite.

I wonder if anyone can point me towards resources / blogs / samples that will show me how to create a data layer that will allow me to target all of the above while still keeping as much of a common code base as possible for my data layer?

I have the vsix extensions for each of the SQLite "flavors" and also the C# wrapper, `System.Data.SQLite`.

Many thanks in advance,

Richard

Answer (score 3):

You are going to have to create a Portable Class Library that can be used by all of those platforms.

In that Portable Class Library, you will need to use an interface  and you will have to pass in the platform-specific implementations (WP8 and WindowsRT will require slightly different implementations).

But here is what helped me. There may be some other resources, but this was definitely the best one and the one that allowed me to do exactly what you are looking to do.

It's a series that I followed (and made a few changes along the way) but it helped me immensely.
http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2013/06/02/Windows-(RT-and-Phone)-and-Sqlite-(Part-1).aspx

Here are some snippets from Part 4 the series:

> create a separate SQLitePCL project and to define a set of interfaces
>   which map to the classes/methods which is exposed by Sqlite-net. I’m
>   not going to bore you with the details but you can see from following
>   image just a couple of the interfaces which will map to classes such
>   as the SQliteConnection, TableMapping and Column.

Regarding the Platform implementations:

> For each platform we need to implement these interfaces. This is
>   really a matter of taking the sqlite-net classes, defined in SQLite.cs
>   and SQliteAsync.cs and modifying them to implement the defined
>   interfaces. This isn’t quite as simple as adjusting the class
>   signature to include the appropriate interface but it isn’t far off.
>
> We need to create a separate class library for each platform, eg
>   SQLiteWinRT and SQLiteWP8. It doesn’t matter which platform you start
>   with (I did the phone implementation first) since you’ll be
>   referencing the same classes using the “add as link” technique
>   discussed in the previous post. You might be thinking, if we’re simply
>   going to be adding the same classes to both libraries why they can’t
>   be all in the shared PCL. The answer lies in the conditional
>   compilation statements at the top of the sqlite-net files – these
>   determine how the classes are built for the respective platforms.

Comment: This is an excellent resource and one that Googling failed to uncover, thank you. Unfortunately, the series is incomplete and lacks a desktop version but it's certainly a step in the right direction.

Comment: Hmm, if your Portable Class Library targets .NET 4.5 then you should be able to pass the Desktop-specific implementation of the sqlite-net interfaces. Perhaps you would just need to add the sqlite-net nuget package to your Desktop project.